# php move_upload_file error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

```
<?php
        $uploaddir = 'media/';
        $file = basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "GOOD";
        } else {
        echo "ERROR";
        }
?>
```

I have this php script on my AWS EC2 linux server. 
And it always return ERROR. I did chmod 777 and chmod 755 but still complains.

What is the problem? This code works just fine with another web server not Amazon EC2. 
Is there any limitation that I can not upload files(images) through php on Amazon EC2?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it by function file_exists..

you can modify your code for better understanding..

```
if($_FILES['photo']['error'] == ''){
    $uploaddir = 'media/';
    $file = basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);

    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;
    if(file_exists($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])){
       if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
          echo "GOOD";
       }
    } 
    else {
       echo "ERROR";
    }

}
else{
    echo "Error In Uploading File";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is error reporting turned on?

Check if there are errors. Simple way to see, what is uploaded:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

debug, debug, debug!